# Excel VBA Macro "run/open" macro on any workbook

Tags: excel, vba

How can I write macro in Excel that will work (to run with shortcut) on any excel document which I will open?

Is this possible?

Comment: I guess this question should have been on superuser..

Comment: what do you mean with that ?

Comment: This question is not completely related to programming, rather it is more to do with how to use excel. stackoverflow.com is a site for programming questions. where superuser.com is site for software usage related questions. In future you can put up any usage related questions in there.

Comment: If you have problems with your macro, come back to StackOverflow and post whatever code you have with a description of where it's breaking and I'm sure you will find the help you need.

Answer (score 4):

You need to add your macros to Personal.xlsb in order to make them available to all the excel files. Choose Personal Macro Workbook in Record Macro dialog to do this quickly.

[image]

Source: http://office.microsoft.com/en-in/excel-help/copy-your-macros-to-a-personal-macro-workbook-HA102174076.aspx

Comment: Thank you I will try. Can I also make an "BACKUP" of these Personal macros if I format hard drive or want to copy to another PC ?

Comment: @thaking PERSONAL.xlsb is saved in C:\Users\ [Username]\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Excel\XLSTART so you can copy it like any other file.